# constants in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i'm creating a wordpress plugin then i realize that i have many vars so i decided to make file with all my constants

> config/constants.php

and i defined my constants like this :

```
<?php
$wilayas = array(
    'ny' => 'New York',
    'la' => 'Los Angles
);
define('wilayas',$cities);
```

my problem that when i wanted to require this file in my plugin construct i always have problem like this :

> Warning: include_once(/config/constants.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/***/public_html/***/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.php on line 14

i tried using 'plugin_dir_url' and 'plugin_dir_path' 
also with 'require' and 'include'
i put it inside and outside the '__construct' and always same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you most likely need is the code:

```
require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'config/constants.php';
```